# \hyperref color change

Tags: xetex, hyperref, color

This command gives me all the clickable content in the red color. How do I change it to green?

```
\usepackage[pdftex,breaklinks,colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,pdftitle={Lecture 9},pdfauthor={Ryan Higginbottom},pdfsubject={LaTeX}]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,
  allcolors=green, %<---  green
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  pdftitle={Lecture 9},
  pdfauthor={Ryan Higginbottom},pdfsubject={LaTeX}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{abc}\label{test}
\ref{test}
\end{document}
```